# Sencha Touch 2 with Phone GAP able to run in IOS and Android with one time develop

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

in my Project Customer having IOS and android OS,
we hope we only need to develop 1 time, then able to use in both Operating system,
isn't Sencha Touch 2 with Phone GAP able to run in IOS and Android without edit any coding? and only develop once.

p/s: i just want to know , if i develop apps with sencha touch, able to run in android and IOS ? both operating with once development. YES or NO ?

Comment: have you [read their marketing material?](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) The large paragraph on their landing page titled "What is Sencha Touch" answers exactly this question...

Comment: @ryancumley "framework that enables developers to build powerful apps that work on iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone, and more." i know it is working in IOS and Android, but there dont have mention the only need develop once, official web site only mention able to run in IOS and android, but maybe different coding? need to modify some code? or only develop once and then use in both operating system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your app is "simple" and has no special requirements regarding performance, it is true, that you do the main work only once.

Sencha Touch runs in a browser and yes it runs in iPhone browser and Android browser as well. Phonegap gives you an app template with a webview (chromeless fullscreen browser) that displays your HTML content developed with Sencha Touch and it adds a Javascript API that enables you to use certain device features that are unavailable to a normal website in a normal browser. That means you develop your app once in HTML/CSS/JS, wrap that content into two different app templates and you have two apps.

But please note that you might want to put some extra work into your web app to enhance the user experience on the different platforms, e. g.

- Android phones have a hardware back button, iPhones don't
- The UI elements look different and the preferred UI patterns differ on both platforms
- Not all sensors or phone features may be accessible or available on both platforms

Comment: i dont get the question's answer from your statement, i just want to know , if i develop apps with sencha touch, able to run in android and IOS ? both operating with once development. YES or NO ?

Comment: Sencha Touch runs in a browser. Phonegap gives you an app template with a webview (chromeless fullscreen browser) that displays your HTML content developed with Sencha Touch. That means you develop your app once in HTML/CSS/JS, wrap it into two different app templates and you have two apps. The main work is shared between both platforms but maybe you have to do some extra work.

Comment: so, can u answer clearly? just need some extra work, some changes coding then able to run in Android and IOS. please change the answer, and i will mark you as ANSWER

Comment: I changed my answer. But without going into more detail and without knowing your requirements it is not possible to answer more precisely.